# Yii2 изменить путь к папке views для модулей в теме?

Tags: yii2, themes, модули

Собственно вопрос в названии темы. По умолчанию получается метровый путь

> @app/themes/basic/modules/blog/views/comment/index.php

Можно как-то укоротить его ? К примеру чтобы было проще

> @app/themes/basic/blog/index.php

где blog назание модуля

Comment: Вы можете создать свой алиас и привязаться уже к нему непосредственно..... как сделать свой алиас? Можете прочитать данный ответ: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28805960/6104996   или данный: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31136099/6104996  .... в результате у вас может быть даже так `@myAlias/index.php`

Comment: Огромное спасибо, так работает :)

Answer (score 0):

В модуле можно настроить viewPath
[доки](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-module.html#$viewPath-detail)

Answer (score 0):

Настройте алиасы в конфиге:

```
return [
// ...
'aliases' => [
    '@app/themes/basic/blog' => '/app/themes/basic/modules/blog/views/comment',
    ],
];
```

[Псевдонимы](https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/doc/guide/2/concept-aliases/)

Answer (score 0):

при обращении к шаблону из контроллера модуля или самого класса модуля можно использовать относительный путь:

> Если имя вида начинается с одинарного слеша /, то вид будет искаться в папке видов по умолчанию текущего модуля . Если активного модуля на данный момент нет, будет использована папка видов приложения по умолчанию, т.е. вид будет искаться в @app/views, как в одном из примеров выше.

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/structure-views#named-views

Кроме того для всех модулей установленных через Composer автоматом добавляется alias(ы) на основании autoload в `composer.json` модуля